# Interpolating and predicting CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, prediction, kalman-filter

I need to get an updated user location with at least 10 hz to animate the location smoothly in MapBox for iOS while driving. Since Core Location only provides one point every second I believe I need to do some prediction.

I have tried [ikalman](https://github.com/lacker/ikalman) but it doesn`t seem to do any difference when updated once a second and queried at 10 hz.

How do i tackle this please?

Comment: just out of curiosity: why 10 Hz? When driving a car a glimpse every three seconds is too often to keep on the road and not hitting obstacles... one idea so to get that is to use the gyroscope and accelerometer data...

Comment: Because if Apple can animate it smoothly, we should be able to as well. A glimpse may be 1-2 seconds long, and during this time it should move along the path nicely and not jump.

Comment: if you update twice a second and animate the position via CoreAnimation the user will get a smooth image... if you update once a second and animate the same way with an animation time of one second, that also should do the trick... and is much simpler than doing lots of math.

Comment: Maybe, but we are using MapBox to display the map and would rather not hack their animations. It's easier to just set the center coordinate of the map more often. There appears to be a library for this as i stated in the question, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe i was using it wrong. Providing an example using ikalman that answers the question is fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using long UIView animations instead (2-3) seconds with easing that start from the current state. This gives the impression of smooth position and heading following "for free".

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is extrapolation, not interpolation.

I'm really, really surprised that there's so few resources on extrapolation on the internet. If you want to know more you should read some numerical methods/math book and implement the algorithm yourself.

Maybe simple linear extrapolation will suffice ?

```
// You need two last points to extrapolate
-(double) getExtrapolatedValueAt:(double)x withPointA:(Point*)A andPointB(Point*)B
{
    // X is time, Y is either longtitute or latitude.
    return A.y + ( x - A.x ) / (B.x - A.x) * (B.y - A.y);
}
-(Point*) getExtrapolatedPointAtTime:(double)X fromLatitudeA:(Point*)latA andLatitudeB:(Point*)latB andLongtitudeA:(Point*)longA andLongtitudeB:(Coord*)longB
{
    double extrapolatedLatitude = [self getExtraploatedValueAt:X withPointA:latA andPointB:latB];
    double extrapolatedLongtitude = [self getExtrapolatedValueAt:X withPointA:longA andPointB:longB];
    Coord* extrapolatedPoint = [Coord new];
    extrapolatedPoint.longtitude = extrapolatedLongtitude;
    extrapolatedPoint.latitude = extrapolatedLatitude;
    return extrapolatedPoint;
}
```

Not sure if I got the function right but you can check here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation

it's really easy.

You should implement the linear extrapolation.
If you find out that linear extrapolation isn't enough (for curves for example) you should just iterate and change it with some other extrapolation algorithm.

Another approach would be to have a 1 sec delay in animation and animate between two known points using interpolation. I don't know if that's acceptable for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is typically solved with something called "Dead Reckoning". And you're right on track with trying to use a Kalman filter for doing this. If iKalman isn't working for you, you can try to resort to a simpler approach.

There's a lot of this sort of problem solving when dealing with games and network latency, so you can likely reuse an algorithm developed for this purpose.

[This seems like a pretty thorough example](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131638/dead_reckoning_latency_hiding_for_.php).

[The wiki on Kalman filters may help out as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter).